# How to handle conflicting type such time_t, time64_t

Tags: mingw, opencl, ubuntu-18.04

I am following a guide on GitHub to build an app.  The guide starts off with

```
sudo apt-get install mingw-w64 cmake
I was then asks to execute cmake foo foo -DBUILD32=OFF more foo
then to run make
```

Things went OK for while.  Errors like cannot find /usr/include : "bits", "sys", "gnu", "asm"
were solved as those folders were in /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
I just moved them into usr/include

However, I do not know how to handle the following "conflicting type" and was looking for help

```
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:130:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:394,
                 from /home/jstateson/Projects/milkywayathome_client/milkyway/include/milkyway_util.h:28,
                 from /home/jstateson/Projects/milkywayathome_client/milkyway/src/milkyway_util.c:21:
/usr/include/bits/types/time_t.h:7:18: error: conflicting types for ‘time_t’
 typedef __time_t time_t;
                  ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/stddef.h:7:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3-win32/include/stddef.h:1,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:33,
                 from /home/jstateson/Projects/milkywayathome_client/milkyway/include/milkyway_util.h:26,
                 from /home/jstateson/Projects/milkywayathome_client/milkyway/src/milkyway_util.c:21:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/crtdefs.h:138:20: note: previous declaration of ‘time_t’ was here
 typedef __time64_t time_t;
                    ^~~~~~
```

The above shows "time_t" but there are hundreds more such as

typedef __ssize_t ssize_t;

__MINGW_EXTENSION typedef __int64 ssize_t;

Answer (score 0):

Found problem:  The compiler include line was
`-DOPENCL_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include`
because the OpenCL library "CL" was in the "include" and the source files all had code such as `#include "CL/cl.h"`

That cause the conflict because that include directive got the entire "include"
I solved this by creating the folder "OpenCL" and putting the folder "CL" into it and then editing the cmake to have `/usr/include/OpenCL`

This was all caused by `sudo apt-get install opencl-headers` going into `/usr/include/CL`